# NancyFX modules are being disposed immediately after being bootstrapped

Tags: nancy

I have written a simple application using Nancy 1.4.5 which has a single NancyModule. I am using Nancy Self Hosting with the default bootstrapper.

I want to dispose all of the Nancy Modules and rediscover them if the app config (for example, current port) changes. Everything appears to be working as far as rediscovery when Nancy is disposed and re-constructed except Dispose is being called at the wrong time.  Dispose seems to be called as part of the discovery process of NancyModules.

In my application startup, i call the following code:

`_host = new NancyHost(hostConf, new Uri($"http://localhost:{Port}"));
_host.Start();`

In my NancyModule I have implemented IDisposable.

As soon as the NancyHost is constructed (before Start() is called), i see the Dispose method in the NancyModule is hit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After playing with more with the TinyIOC container registration i figured out what was happening.

The NancyModule implementing class is constructed/disposed during initial auto registration.
It is also constructed/disposed every time a route is called.

This is not ideal behavior for my application as the backing behind the service is a persistent connection and reconnecting each time a route is called was adding ~100ms response time to each request.

In the end I implemented an unwanted hack as I don't know what else to do.  I have created a static singleton instance of the persistent connection service that can be reset through a function in the singleton. That way even though the NancyModule is constructed during each call to a route, there is not a performance hit by wiring up the backend connection each time.

It would be better if there was a way to set the NancyModule as a singleton registration for TinyIOC, but it seemed that even if I explicitly set it as so by doing a custom container registration, it was still being constructed each time it was called.

Comment: Can you post your tinyioc registration for the connection pls?

Answer (score 0):

Are you overriding `ConfigureApplicationContainer` or `ConfigureRequestContainer` in your BootStrapper?

```
protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
{
    base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

    // ...
}

protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(TinyIoCContainer container, NancyContext context)
{
    base.ConfigureRequestContainer(container, context);

    // ...
}
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Bootstrapping-nancy):

- ConfigureApplicationContainer - This is called once, when the Bootstrapper is executed, and is used to register dependencies that you either wish to have application scope lifetimes (application singletons), or be registered as multi-instance:
- ConfigureRequestContainer - This is called once per request, before the module matching the route is resolved, and is used to register singletons that will have request lifetime.